# Get correct time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some code that I modified from a site which returns a date like this:

> Mon Feb 20 2017 10:40:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)

What I'm trying to achieve is to make it look like:

> 10:40
>
> 20-02-2017

Here's what I got:

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=Date()">Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="time"></p>
```

I have tried with `Date(hh:mm)` and `Date(dd-mm-yyyy)` but it didn't worked.

Comment: try to use moment library

Comment: If you want to specify using a formatting string have a look at MomentJS. For simple usecases you can do the same using `getDay()`, `getMonth()` etc.

Comment: @newbie, it is working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.getDate()`,`.getMonth()`,`.getFullYear()`,`.getHours()`,`.getMinutes()` methods in order to get `date` details.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var date=new Date();
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=(date.getDate()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getFullYear()+'<br>'+date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes());
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="time"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) Object methods:

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  var d = new Date(),
      hours = ('0' + (d.getHours())).slice(-2),
      minutes = ('0' + (d.getMinutes())).slice(-2),
      day = ('0' + (d.getDate())).slice(-2),
      month = ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
      year = d.getFullYear(),
      dateString = hours + '-' + minutes + '<br>' + 
        day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
  
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = dateString;
};
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="time"></p>
```